# Adobe Acrobat submit a form with 'Mailto' only emailing inputted information

Tags: adobe, acrobat

As the question states above, using acrobats submit a form function with the 'mailto'script, only emails the inputted information on the form, I would like to email the *entire* form, information and template on the singe PDF file, is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the code below to meet your specific needs. Add it to the Submit button MouseUp action.

```
this.mailDoc({
    cTo: "apstory@example.com",
    cCC: "dpsmith@example.com",
    cSubject: "The Latest News",
    cMsg: "A.P., attached is my latest news story in PDF."
});
```

It will launch the default mail application with the parameters set by the code.